# Reading text file from host system and docker container yields different results

Tags: java, docker, encoding

I want to read a textfile line by line in an application that is running inside a docker container. The file contains paths to some other files and i want to mess around with these.

Because the file is also read by a vb6 program it is required to be encoded in ISO-8859-1.

When I read the file on my docker host machine (ubuntu 18.04.3) everything works. But when I read it inside my docker container, special characters are not read properly.

This is my Code:

```
String n = "/foo/bar.txt";
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(n),StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
for(String line : lines) {
    File[] directories = new File(line).listFiles(File::isDirectory);
}
```

On my host machine, `directories` is correctly populated, but inside the docker-container it is `null`.

I identified the problem being the speciel character `ä`. When I print out the bytes, on the host machine it is: `-61 -92` while inside the container it is `63`.

The container is derived from amazoncoretto:8,

I hope sombody can help.

Comment: -62 -92  for ä means StandardCharsets.UTF_8 - the default for Ubuntu. I am baffled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a bit of fiddeling around i discovered, that the standard Charset of teh docker container was set to ASCII, I have no idea why.

So all I had to do was set the default encoding for java at teh startup of the program with
 `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MainClass`